# Using Aurelia Validation to validate a list

Tags: validation, aurelia

I am using Aurelia validation to validate items within my Aurelia project. I am currently trying to validate that an array contains at least 1 item. I have the following validation rule set up:

```js
ValidationRules
    .ensure((x: Appraisal) => x.objectives)
    .minItems(1)
    .withMessage("You must add at least one objective before submitting.")
    .on(Appraisal);
```

And I have the following html:

```html
<div class="au-animate" repeat.for="objective of appraisal.objectives">
    <compose view-model="./appraisal-objective-item" model.bind="{ objective: objective, appraisal: appraisal }" />
</div>
```

Currently, when I call validate on my validation controller, the `result.valid` is always true.

What do I need to do in my html so that the validation is 'captured' by the validation controller? (i.e. you would normally have `value.bind="firstName & validate"` for a value field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defaut, aurelia-validation only validates the binded properties. If you want to validate a whole entity, even if some of the properties aren't used in data bindings, you must use the controller's `addObject(object, rules?)` method.

In your case:

```js
this.appraisal = new Appraisal();
this.validationController.addObject(this.appraisal);
```

Don't forget to call the `removeObject` method if needed. (For example if you change the value of the `appraisal` property.)

You will find more details about the entity validation here:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/9

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using addObject. I wasn't sure about how I would render my errors in the UI, but I am doing it manually now by getting a list of errors from the controller.